# How to Make input field empty but have predefined default output value in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, jsx

I am trying to traverse form data from child to parent and parent to another child and so on. But I want to have my input field empty initially and have pre-populated data on desired output tag. If I use a value tag on input and use "useState" then the value gets automatically populated with whatever default I have given on "UseState"

Child.js

```
import React from "react";

const Child = ({ user, setUser }) => {
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setUser((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    }));
  };

  const formOnChageHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };
  const fromOnSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <form onChange={formOnChageHandler} onSubmit={fromOnSubmitHandler}>
        <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
        <input
          id="name"
          placeholder="Enter Name"
          value={user.name}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="age">Age:</label>
        <input
          id="age"
          placeholder="Enter Age"
          value={user.age}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </form>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
export default Child;
```

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Child from "./components/Child";
import Child2 from "./components/Child2";

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    name: "Surojit Manna",
    age: "23"
  });

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Child user={user} setUser={setUser} />
      <h1>Getting From Parent Element</h1>
      <h4>Your name is:{user.name}</h4>
      <h4>Your age is:{user.age}</h4>
      {/* Passing data from parent to another child {Child2} from Child1 */}
      <Child2 data={user} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Codesandbox-
https://codesandbox.io/s/from-traversing-child-to-parent-to-another-child-ynwyqd?file=/src/App.js:0-581

Comment: have default user state with empty values ...

Comment: I need to have a default initial value on the output section & empty input box initially. By having the default user state empty, the value on the output section will also be empty, which is not my goal.

Comment: @isuro You should create a separate state specifically for the inputs. Doing it any other way is considered bad practice. Then you can set the new state to empty and the inputs will be empty.

Comment: That will not be dry code & also if I didn't maintain a single state then every input element will be rerendered and over right the previous output. I have tried it just before.

Answer (score 2):

a simple hack is that you can handle it accordingly in the child/parent components like, what should be rendered when there is no data in the input fields.

```
  const Child2 = (props) => {
  const {name, age} = props.data
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Child 2</h1>
      <h4>Your name is:{name?name:'defaultvalue'}</h4>
      <h4>Your age is:{age?age:'defaultvalue'}</h4>
      {/* Passing data to another deep child element */}
      <Child3 data={props.data} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

and for the parent,

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Child user={user} setUser={setUser} />
      <h1>Getting From Parent Element</h1>
      <h4>Your name is:{user.name?user.name:'defaultvalue'}</h4>
      <h4>Your age is:{user.age?user.age:'defaultvalue'}</h4>
      {/* Passing data from parent to another child {Child2} from Child1 */}
      <Child2 data={user} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: That's what I was looking for in Angular we do it somehow similarly but got lost in react. Thank you so much for the much-needed help.